# Using Images in a Custom IME

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, soft-keyboard

I have been attempting to implement a custom SoftKeyboard (IME) which contains and outputs icons for keys. Think emoji.  I have skinned the keys, but injecting the selected drawable into the String Builder has proven difficult. I decided to implement my own ImageGetter so that I could control what was returned by Html.fromHtml(). The fromHtml method continues to act as if it's returning null even though I know that the drawable is not null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I based this project off of the SoftKeyboard sample. I targeted the file, SoftKeyboard.java an instance of

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService 
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
```

This class instantiates an object mComposing, this is used to store the text entered into the edit box from the soft keyboard.

```
private StringBuilder mComposing = new StringBuilder();
```

I thought that I could append the images as a Spanned to the StringBuilder and display the image that way. What happens here is that a white square with "obj" text in it shows instead of the selected icon, meaning getDrawable() is returning null.

I have tried a few things with the bounds but I am not sure if I am close or if I am going down the wrong path.

Declaring my drawable in onCreate:

```
 mHangingDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hanging_tiny);
 mHangingDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, mHangingDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), mHangingDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

In handleCharacter(int, int[]) I wrote this catch for codes that I have personally mapped.

```
else if (primaryCode == 50) {
        String htmlSource = "<img src='hanging_small' />";
        ImageGetter ig = new ImageGetter(){

            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {


                return mHangingDrawable;
            }

        };
        Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(htmlSource, ig, null);
        mComposing.append(htmlSpan);

        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(mComposing, 1);
```

}

This article about [Creating Input Methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) was a helpful resource.

Comment: What is `mComposing`?

Comment: I have updated the question to include some more information.